# C++ inheritance, interfaces

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface

Let's say I do have an interface `IControllable`, 3 classes inherits that interface: `MachineControllable, LightControllable, OtherControllable` which has some specific data and methods to them.

Now I do want to have only one container of all `IControllable`, so I do create a vector container.

```
vector<IControllable> allControllables; // and put all the MachineControllable,
//LightControllable, OtherControllable here by the IControllable interface class.
```

But the problem now, that I can only use what the `IControllable` defines, not the specific data and methods of specific Controllable.

Should I have seperate containers for each Controllable, or how my logic is wrong in terms of OOP ?

Answer (score 4):

> *"Should I have seperate containers for each Controllable, or how my logic is wrong in terms of OOP ?"*

No, your logic is OK. The problem is, you can't instatiate an abstract class.

You should have a container keeping pointers to the `IControllable` interface, like:

```
 vector<IControllable*> allControllables;
```

or

```
 vector<std::unique_ptr<IControllable>> allControllables;
```

or

```
 vector<std::shared_ptr<IControllable>> allControllables;
```

Comment: Probably  not `unique_ptr`; it's very rare that a container should own such objects.  Possibly  `shared_ptr`, but most of the time, a raw pointer is most appropriate.

Comment: Yes, thought the same about unique_ptr but the answer clears all clouds, thanks.

Comment: One other point: the fact that his code compiles makes me think that his `IControllable` isn't abstract (which may be design error on his part---interface classes normally should be abstract).

Comment: @JamesKanze I didn't see any evidence, the OP stated, that the code compiles.

Comment: It's hard to be sure, since English clearly isn't the OPs native language, but a statement like "that I can only use what the IControllable defines" seems to indicate that he can use some things; ie the code compiles.

Comment: @JamesKanze I would say it is more usual for containers to own their objects because it is more usual, and preferable, to store the objects by value and not pointer. The only reason to use pointers here is to facilitate polymorphism and/or prevent slicing. So the natural first choice, for me, would be the `unique_ptr`. I think `shared_ptr` should the rarer choice but I suspect it gets over-used.

Comment: @Galik Containers _always_ own what they contain, because they contain a copy of what was put in them.  In this case, the container will "own" the pointers you put in them.  It's very rare for a container to own pointed too objects,

Comment: @JamesKanze When you put a *smart pointer* in the container then it *does* own the object pointed to. So I was just saying in *those* cases I believe it is more usual for a container to hold *unique* ownership especially in this case where the original intention was to own the object by storing it *by value* and the only reason for storing it *by pointer* is to avoid *slicing* and facilitate *polymorphism*. Otherwise choosing between *unique semantics* and *shared semantics* is solving a *different* problem

Comment: @Galik I've yet to find a case in real life where you''d want a container of `std::unique_ptr`.  _Most_ of the time I've needed containers of pointers, it has been for navigation, in some form or another; in which case, raw pointers are called for.

Comment: @JamesKanze I *completely* agree with you regarding *raw pointers*. I did prepare a post in response but this is not really the forum for discussions, so I'll just agree to differ :)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, your vector should contain pointers of some kind, not the base object itself.

Once you have that, you need a way to get the specific pointer to the actual object type in the container. The standard way is with `dynamic_cast`:

```
IMachineControllable * p = dynamic_cast<IMachineControllable*>(allControllables[i]);
```

If you choose the wrong type, you'll get a NULL pointer.

If these are Microsoft COM interfaces there's an alternate method you need to use instead, but I won't go into that unless you state that's what you have.

Comment: Was just thinking about that, and had the same idea of casts, thanks for the example.
I do have a cloudy knowledge of c++/oop already, just sometimes its hard to put it all together ^^

Comment: I'd be very sceptical of an interface which requires `dynamic_cast` to work.  There are cases where it is appropriate, but they are rare.  He should be able to use the objects via virtual functions in the interface.

Comment: Can you please give an example of "He should be able to use the objects via virtual functions in the interface" @JamesKanze ?

Answer (score 1):

That's probably not the only problem.  Containers require value
semantics, and contain *copies* of the object you put into
them.  Inheritance doesn't generally work well with copy and
assignment: think of what it might mean if you have:

```
*p = *q;
```

where `p` and `q` are `IControllable*`, but `p` points to a
`MachineControllabe`, but `q` to a `LightControllable`.  As a
general rules (and there *are* exceptions), you should make
interfaces uncopiable and unassignable.  Also, typically, they
will also contain pure virtual functions, which means that you
can't instantiate them.  In either case,
`std::vector<IControllable>` wouldn't even compile.

What you probably want is `std::vector<IControllable*>`.
Polymorphism only works through pointers or references anyway
(and you cannot have a vector of references).

Comment: Can you please give an example of "He should be able to use the objects via virtual functions in the interface" @James Kanze ?

Comment: @Tomas Do you know what a virtual function is?  Or what a pure virtual function is: an interface normally contains pure virtual functions.  (Otherwise, it isn't an interface.)  Usually, in a polymorphic hierarchy, all of the behavior should be available through pure virtual functions in the interface.  (There are exceptions when the derived class extends the interface, or implements more than one interface.  But you should start simple, where this is not the case.)

Answer (score 1):

> But the problem now, that I can only use what the IControllable
>   defines, not the specific data and methods of specific Controllable.
>
> Should I have seperate containers for each Controllable, or how my
>   logic is wrong in terms of OOP ?

This depends on what you want to do with your objects.

If you need to make *heavy* use of all the `IControllable` objects through the `IControllable` interface then putting them all in one container makes sense.

If, on the other hand, you want to make *heavy* use of their *specific* interfaces then having separate containers also makes sense.

If you need to do both then there is nothing wrong with doing both.

Now if you choose to put everything in one container then you must use some kind of pointer/smart pointer because storing different types *by value* would cause slicing and would not allow *polymorphic* execution.

However It is preferable to store objects in containers by *value* if possible. So if you go with *multiple* containers storing *by value* would be preferable.

If you want to do both then you could store the objects by value in separate containers and store their pointer in a catch-all container. In that case the stored-by-value containers will **own** the objects and so the catch-all container should **not** own them - use raw pointers for that:

```
struct IControllable { virtual ~IControllable() {} };
struct MachineControllable: IControllable {};
struct LightControllable: IControllable {};
struct OtherControllable: IControlable {};

// store by value if possible (not always possible)
std::vector<MachineControllable> machingControlables;
std::vector<LightControllable> lightControlables;
std::vector<OtherControlable> otherControlables;

std::vector<IControlable*> allControlables; // raw pointers (non owned)
```

If you don't want to store your objects separately then your catch-all container needs to **own** the objects:

```
// these objects die when this container dies.
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IControlable>> allControlables;
```

So the real question is how are you going to spend most of your time processing these as specific types and/or general (base) types?

And also how complex do you want your data structures? If you use multiple containers then that increases the complexity of managing the data.

Bear in mind if you don't use separate containers for your *specific* types you will have to cast them to make *specific* calls:

```
for(auto& controlable: allControlables)
{
    MachineControllable* mc;
    LightControllable* lc;
    OtherControllable* oc;

    if((mc = dynamic_cast<MachineControllable*>(controlable.get())))
        mc->machine_specific();
    else if((lc = dynamic_cast<LightControllable*>(controlable.get())))
        lc->light_specific();
    else if((oc = dynamic_cast<OtherControllable*>(controlable.get())))
        oc->other_specific();
}
```

Not ideal.